How to create a 2 x 2 Cross tab from 4 columns?w
I am new to Tableau and need help creating a table visualisation.
Currently the data looks like this:



1A
1B
2A
2C




4
3
4
5


2
5
3
1



But what I am wanting is a crosstab that sums the columns so that it looks like this:




1
2




A
6
7


B
8
6



How do I do this?
I have tried to create each of values individually and manually insert them into a 'pseudo table' that is made up of containers in the dash but would prefer it if there was a table visualisation that I could develop on one sheet to put into the dashboard.
Thank you!

The easiest approach is to reshape your data source, say to have 3 columns Letter, Number, Value. Then you treat (if necessary, convert) the Letter and Number fields as Dimensions in Tableau.
Then put Letter on Rows, and Number on Columns (make sure it is a dimension), and Sum(Value) on the text shelf to get your table.
Tableau Prep Builder is helpful for reshaping data in an automated way. You can reshape by first pivoting your four columns to make a two column table, with columns called say tag and value, then add calculated fields to pull out the two characters in the tag to create Letter and Number fields. You could use the First() and Last() functions to do that. Then you can hide the tag field if you like.
For simple reshaping tasks like this, you can also do it completely within Tableau Desktop if you prefer. If you haven’t pivoted a data source before, see the online help from Tableau to learn how.
